# Design procedure for switched capacitor dc-dc converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, design, switching-regulator

I am looking for some references to design a switched capacitor dc-dc converter, however I could hardly find any reference online.

I am aware that the design method depends on the actual topology of the converter but, are there any guidelines for anyone topology, say I am looking for series parallel step down topology.

Through design procedure I want to find the output capacitor value along with fly capacitors to support given output current and voltage ripple.

I could only manage to get general recommendations from TI LM2770, where it's recommended to use Cfly= 0.1 Co
and Co recommended is 10 uF.

[image]
Please help to come up with design procedure to meet design specs such as switching frequency, output current, output ripple, efficiency etc.
Any references is much appreciated.

Comment: The design procedure is: use 10uF, 1uF. I don't see much point in using anything else. What were you expecting?

Comment: `Through design procedure I want to find the output capacitor value along with fly capacitors to support given output current and voltage ripple.` As stated in the datasheet there's no formula or approximation for that. All you can do is to read the test results and waveforms of the test circuits and decide what to use. Apparently, for most of the applications with that IC, C1 = 1uF and Cin = Cout = C2 = 10 uF should be alright.

Comment: The snapshot just quotes one reference I could get online. I need to design a converter which can have totally different specs for voltage conversion ratio and the output current. So, I want to know how can I come up with capacitor values in that case. I am not using this IC.

Comment: So, what governs these capacitor values? How do I choose them based on design specs? This is something I want to know.

Comment: Then why are you referencing an IC, that you aren't using, that doesn't contain a design procedure? I don't understand.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem: you have problem X (design a switched-capacitor converter for unstated ratio, range, current, size, etc.), and are looking for solutions Y (how to design for, well, all of that..). Are you designing an IC? Why choose switched-capacitor at all? There seem to be underlying problems here, that would be better asked directly.

Comment: Sorry, I think the reference IC creates confusion here. I want to design a switch cap DC DC converter for given specs and I want to know how to proceed for that, figuring out capacitor values etc. I attached the snapshot to mention that these are some general recommendations however I am not sure how do I obtain these values for given output current and ripple spec in my case. Any equations or rules? Sorry for the confusion again!